# how to check if there is a cycle by given set of edges

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

i have a matrix(5х5) for example in a dataframe and each iteration I add new edge to array, for example:

```
[[1,2][2,3][3,4]]
```

and the I add one more,[4,1] for example:

```
[[1,2][2,3][3,4],[4,1]]
```

but I don't want a cycle less than 5 length for edges here, how can I check if there is a cycle using python?

(I just want to ban for ex [4,1] in order to avoid cycle less than 5 length)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why would that be a cycle? Because it ends in `1` and then your first item starts with `1`? (I'm just trying to figure out what _cycle_ is in this problem)

Comment: @BorrajaX yes, [1,2] means that i =1 and j=2 in adjacency matrix. So I'd like to avoid all cycle in the set that are less than 5 length

Comment: So... Would it be enough with checking wether the `y` (`[1]`) of your new item appears among `x` (`[0]`) of the items of the existing matrix (the first 5)? I mean... would this suffice? `new=[4,1]; matrix=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]; print("Loop? %s" % (True if new[1] in {a[0] for a in matrix[:5]} else False))`

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is already known problem called network connectivity problem.

I assume you know a thing or two about Graph theory.

We can easily follow the next algorithm called quick-find ( it works for small set of Edges)

The idea is we split the graph into subsets..  and we iterate over each edge entry.. If they are already in a subset then it's cyclic , if not union them

---

How to represent sets
Simply we will use dictionary where keys are the vertices and the values are the index of the subset .

Initially each vertex is in its own subset till it's joined with another one.

When we Join two subsets we simply change the values of the dictionary of the subsets' vertices to be the same

```
Vertices = {}

def updateConnection(old,new):
    for k,v in Vertices.items():
        if v == old:
            Vertices[k] = new

def unite(v1,v2):
    newpid = Vertices[v1]
    oldpid = Vertices[v2]
    updateConnection(oldpid,newpid)
def isConnected(v1,v2):
    return Vertices[v1] == Vertices[v2]

def isCyclic(Edges):
    for edge in Edges:
        if not edge[0] in Vertices.keys():
            Vertices[edge[0]] = edge[0]
        if not edge[1] in Vertices.keys():
            Vertices[edge[1]] = edge[1]

        if isConnected(edge[0],edge[1]):
            return True
        unite(edge[0],edge[1])
    return False
```